# Can be achieve SSL Pinning via Certificate with Alamofire in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

SSL Pinning via Certificate with Alamofire

Need to implement SSL Pinning via Certificate from Alamofire.Becuase I am available to implement this, via URL
override func serverTrustEvaluator(forHost host: String) throws -> ServerTrustEvaluating? {
var policy: ServerTrustEvaluating?

```
    /// Smarter check would be beneficial here, theoretically, MITM attack can have an URL containing this string
    if host.contains("stackoverflow.com") {
        /// You could dig even deeper and write your own evaluator
        policy = PublicKeysTrustEvaluator()
    } else {
        /// Deny all other connections
        policy = DenyEvaluator()
    }

    return policy
}
```

but I need to implement this SSL Pinning via Certificate from Alamofire.